# Split nested JSON for multiple flot charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, flot

I've made a simple ajax script (see code) which takes ID values from checkboxes that the user pressed, queries a database and construct a nested JSON-array for flot (containing one array for each ID chosen). Basically everything things work just perfect and all the arrays are being showed in the diagram. However, I'am looking for a solution to get the data, but instead of plotting them in the same diagram, I want to plot each JSON-array in the nested JSON-array in a separate diagram.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/getjson.php",
    data: $('.ids:checked').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(datasets){
        var options = {
            series: {
                lines: { show: true },
                points: { show: true }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%H:%M:%S",
                twelveHourClock: true, 
                timezone: "browser"
            },grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
            }
        }
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), datasets, options);
    }   
});
```

I was thinking to dynamically creating the needed number of divs, maybe with a for-loop and then looping through the each array in the JSON. But I'm not sure how to do this? I could make my own parser and remove the outer-array so that I can simply split the array, but perhaps there is a better solution?
Another solution might be to make a .ajax call for each id-input from the checkboxes.

An example of an JSON where the ID are chosen can be seen here http://dinbab.dk/barline.json

Answer (score 0):

Hei
I've just did something like that.
I needed a diagaram for each channel variable i had in db. What i did was putting the list of channelNames in ViewBag and used razor to create correct number of divs for the diagrams like that:

```
<div id="chartsDiv" class="column">
    @{
        int index = 0;
        int heightDiv = 85 / (ViewBag.Channels.Count + 1);}
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Channels)
    {
        <div id="@item.Replace(" ","")" title="@item" class="plot" style="height:@heightDiv%;"></div>
        index++;
    }
</div>
```

Then in script i do this:

```
var graphsArray = [];
var dataDetail;
$(function () {
    var channelstxt = ('@ViewBag.ChannelsSerialized').replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
    var channels = JSON.parse(channelstxt);
    var seriestxt = ('@ViewBag.SeriesJson').replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    var seriesTab = jQuery.parseJSON(seriestxt);

$.each(channels, function (index, value) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(value.toString().replace(/\s/g, ''));  
    var graph = $.plot(elem, [seriesTab[index]], getOptions(value));
    graphsArray.push(graph)});
    });
```

I get everything from ViewBag but you can easily get serialized json from ajax call.

I hope it helps! Ask it anything is unclear

Comment: Well, out solution doesn't include the use of ASP.NET unfortunately. It's pure PHP, HMTL and JQuery

Comment: You can do the same using ajax and javascript.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that, according to your example